# Scheme REPL in Scheme don't render prompt when user press enter

Tags: scheme, read-eval-print-loop

I've written Scheme REPL that works in all implementations I've tested, but have problem when when someone press enter and don't type anything.

```lisp
(define void (if #f #f))

(cond-expand
  (lips)
  (kawa)
  (gambit)
  (guile (define (flush-output-port) void))
  (gauche (define (flush-output-port) (flush (current-output-port)))))

(let ((repl (lambda ()
              (let ((env (interaction-environment)))
                (let iter ()
                  (display "scheme> ")
                  (flush-output-port)
                  (let ((input (read)))
                     (if (eof-object? input)
                         (newline)
                         (let ((result (eval input env)))
                           (if (not (eq? result void))
                               (begin
                                 (display result)
                                 (newline)))
                           (iter)))))))))
  (repl))
```

How to fix my REPL so it works as expected when someone type enter, it should also work when user tried to exit the REPL by using CTRL+D. Right now it don't print prompt when you enter empty input.

NOTE: I was told that my void may don't work in every implementation, but even SRFI use this (I've learned about this in [Sketchy Scheme book](https://www.t3x.org/sketchy/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my REPL:

```lisp
(let ((repl (lambda ()
              (let ((env (interaction-environment)))
                (let iter ()
                  (display "scheme> ")
                  (flush-output-port)
                  (if (char=? (peek-char) #\newline)
                      (begin
                         (read-char)
                         (iter)))
                  (let ((input (read)))
                     (if (eof-object? input)
                         (newline)
                         (let ((result (eval input env)))
                           (if (not (eq? result void))
                               (begin
                                 (display result)
                                 (newline)))
                            (if (and (char-ready?) (char=? (peek-char) #\newline))
                                (read-char))
                            (iter)))))))))
  (repl))
```